# Why does IMPORTXML with XPATH return unexpected blank row in addition to expected result?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, import

I'm importing into Google Sheets with IMPORTXML with the following XPATH:

```
=IMPORTXML(A2;"//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/ul/li")
```

A2 containing the URL (https://stt.wiki/wiki/20th_Century_Pistol).

From the website I want to import the list entries in the "Basic" column and "Crafted From" row of the table.

There are only two list entries in this section of the table:

- "x1 Basic Security Codes" and
- "x4 Basic Casing"

Therefore, I expected to get only those two list entries as rows in my sheet.
Instead, I got an additional blank row above those two entries. When I change "td[1]" to "td[3]" in the XPATH query however, there are no extra blanks.

I don't understand where the additional blank row is coming from and how I can avoid it.

[Google Sheet with desired and actual result](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Yf1Hw0l0Z-JXdHH182vDOHM8uFoWTC9qi3S7URjFe8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Update: I've been trying to modify the answers from Tanaike and E.Wiest to make their solution work for other cells and sites as well. Tanaike's and E.Wiests solution relies on the `[@style='white-space:nowrap']` element to be present. But this is not the case for other cells (see column "Uncommon" for example). I tried to exclude the sup element explicitly with something along the line of `li[not(contains(@style,'float'))]`, which didn't work. As I still don't understand why Google sheets parses an additional blank line from the "sup" element in the first place, I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw the HTML of the URL, there are 2 `li` tags in the `ul` tag. So I think that your xpath is correct. But from your issue, I was worry that the `sup` tag might affect to this situation. But I'm not sure whether this is the direct reason. So I would like to propose to add the attribute of `li` for your xpath as follows.

#### Modified xpath:

When your xpath is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/ul/li
```

To:

```
//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/ul/li[@style='white-space:nowrap']
```

- By adding `[@style='white-space:nowrap']`, the value of `li` with `style='white-space:nowrap'` is retrieved.

#### Result:

The formula is `=IMPORTXML(A1;"//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/ul/li[@style='white-space:nowrap']")`. Please put the URL to the cell "A1".

[image]

#### Note:

- Also, you can use the xpath of `//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/ul/li[position()>1]`.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the very neat @Tanaike's answer, another expression :

```
=IMPORTXML(A2;"//th[contains(.,'Crafted')]/following::td[1]//li[contains(@style,'white')]")
```

If a blank line is added it's because GoogleSheets parses an additional blank `li` element containing a `@style` attribute.